# how to get a file path with the name and the kind of the file using python

Tags: python, file

so I am getting a name of and I know it's an EXE file.
I need to get the path which the file is at.
It could be anywhere in the computer.
Is there a muddle for it? or a simple script that I am missing?

Comment: Did you use  python library "OS"

Comment: @Zviad i can use it if that what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

files = os.listdir(path='.') # getting all files in currect directory

def get_path(files):
    filename = ""

    for file in files:
        if file == "main.py": # replace "filename.exe" with the name of the file
            filename = file # saving the name of the file in a variable
            break
        elif re.match(r"^\.", file):
            get_path(os.listdir(file))

    absolute_path = os.path.abspath(filename) # absolute path to the file
    return absolute_path

print(get_path(files))
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be in the same directory

Comment: @yotamrec I have edited the code. put it in the very root of your system if you want to search for ALL files. `get_path` will return the absolute path of the first found .exe file.

Comment: @yotamrec sorry, I did not read your question correctly. I changed the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os

file_name = 'the_file_to_find.exe'

for root, _, files in os.walk('\\'):
    if file_name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file_name))
        break
```

However, searching in the whole '\' can be slow, so it would be better to be more precise.